# Dropdown is not displaying on hover

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website. I ran into a slight issue which I haven't been able to fix.
I am trying to make a dropdown menu show up, using 'hover' in CSS, but it is not showing up for some reason.

Here is my HTML code:

```
      <div>
<button class="button button1"> Our Mission</button>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="button button3">What We Do</button>

  <div class="display_things">
    <section class="column">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Our donations</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a>Event 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a>Event 2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a>Event 3</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
    </section>
    <section class="column">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Our Community Work</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a>Event 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a>Event 2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a>Event 3</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
    
    
  </div>
</div>     
<button class="button button4">Donate!</button>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .button3 { 
      background-color: #00ff9d; 
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      width:400px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      }

    .display_things {
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin: 10px;
      background-color: lawngreen;
      display: none; 
      width: 1100px;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .button3:hover .display_things{
      display: block;
    }

    .button4 { 
      background-color: #f4740b; 
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 170px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      width:400px;
    }

    .button:hover{
      background-color: green;

    }
```

Can anyone tell me why exactly the drop-down is not working? I wanted it to be displayed whenever the button is hovered over.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using *:hover*, so your version `.button3:hover .display_things {` should include either a **+** or **~**, as you're trying to select a sibling.

---

So you need to change the selector to either;

`.button3:hover + .display_things {` (for **adjacent** sibling)

OR

`.button3:hover ~ .display_things {` (for **general** sibling, if you are to place anything(s) between the hover and show elements)

Either will work in your code.